# Why was the "is-jad-the-best-java-decompiler" post deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions, close-reasons

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353/is-jad-the-best-java-decompiler) at SO living for a long time (around 2 years) available, with a great amount of views. I can see it why it was closed as "argumentative" a few months ago, but I don't see the point in deleting it.

The FAQ said that a post should be "extremely off topic" (it wasn't, it was programming related), "of very low quality" (it was argumentative but not low quality) and "not useful as signpoint" (it was viewed by a lot of people, and was one of the few posts in the internet about JD-GUI) to be deleted.

So why?

Comment: For reference, [this is what the question used to look like](http://web.archive.org/web/20100728124243/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353/is-jad-the-best-java-decompiler).

Comment: Thanks to you, I checked out the question.  Now I want to punch myself in the face, its so blatantly awful.

Comment: Useful knowledge deleted? Why would somebody do that? Oh dear, I hoped that I will read a closed useful questions someday later, but now see that they will be deleted by the "censorship-members" that are information-saturated and have an interest on removing useful knowledge. Welcome to the world of the real.

Comment: The highest-scoring answer in the Wayback Machine copy @IlmariKaronen posted is a good example of what was wrong with that question. It's just a link to a competing product with no explanation of what makes it better. Not that an explanation would have helped; what's "best" depends on what you're using it for, so what's best for one person might not be best for another. That said, I no longer reflexively flag posts asking for the best X, but the question must present specific use case(s). As Jeff used to say, the goal is to teach how to evaluate a product, not just say "use this one."

Comment: Also, you've misinterpreted the signpost comment. It's not about leaving signs for other places on the Internet. It's about leaving signs for other posts on the same site (in this case, SO). See the blog post [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions that ask about "best" this or that are always off-topic.

They are argumentative and subjective and therefor should be closed.

It is also not something very helpful (why is something considered the "best"?) and the answer could change over time.

Comment: I see why it was closed. The delete reason is what I don't see.

Comment: @SztupY - Probably for cleanup. The fact that it is old and popular does not make it suitable. It is now also one less question for someone to point at and ask "why did my question get deleted when this one exists".

Answer (score 4):

At least two of the "answers" to that question were posted by people who appeared to have strong affiliations with a jad derivative product directly but made no attempt to disclose them.

It wasn't a great question for SO and it seems to have been attracting spam.

Comment: As far as I can tell, [JAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) is [abandonware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware), so I kind of doubt the "affiliations with jad" bit. But yes, some of the answers do seem a bit spammy. Plus, there are plenty of better questions about Java decompilers on SO, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - spot the link between http://stackoverflow.com/a/990503 on the first Q and http://stackoverflow.com/a/990495 on the second and the reposted dupe on http://stackoverflow.com/a/1001821

Comment: Heh, I would if I could; I don't actually have mod privs on SO.  And digging through the Wayback Machine for a random deleted answer is a pain, even if it happens to be archived there.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - ah sorry. It looked like a classic spam + sockpuppet combo which I flagged and consequently brought the whole question to the attention of a moderator.